# An internal error occurred during: "Launching Java Project". java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, remote-debugging, eclipse-rse

I have researched this topic, but I've only been able to find [examples that relate to Android development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847674/an-internal-error-occurred-during-launching-project-java-lang-nullpointerexc). I am developing in pure Java, without the additional Android libraries.

I run Eclipse on a Windows environment. I also use Eclipse to create and run remote PHP and Java projects on a Linux server. But I am now unable to run any Java programs using Eclipse using the RSE plugin for Linux.

So far, I have tried:

- Re-installing the plugin
- Deleting the metadata folder
- Re-defining the work-space
- Uninstalling and re-installing Eclipse

I can run my code using the command prompt. But why does the error message `An internal error occurred during: "Launching Java Project". java.lang.NullPointerException` appear and how can I resolve it?

Comment: I would appreciate if anyone could give me some hints