# Failing to run debugger on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I've tried using the debugger for Java SE on eclipse (Luna). But It doesn't work (breakpoints don't toggle either).

This is what I get when I try running the debugger on a class named 'Execute'.

The Error
[image: The error]
The content of the log (part 1)
[image]
The content of the log (part2)
[image: The content of the log (part2)]

Comment: Try disabling your antivirus and running it.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look [at this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847674/an-internal-error-occurred-during-launching-project-java-lang-nullpointerexc) as it's been asked before.

Comment: I visited both solutions, they don't seem to work.

Comment: Change your project workspace location and setup your project and try to debug again

Comment: Attach [Error Log](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it goes without saying that trying to solve this on my local eclipse didn't work. So I just re-downloaded a newer version, and it works now.